# Can point to a integer array be used to modify the array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing this code for test string literal and integer array. I need someone to help me to check and lighten me.

1).

```
 char NUM[] = "ABC";
 char *p_NUM=NUM;

 NUM[0]='D';

 puts(p_NUM);

 return 0;
```

if you create an array from a string literal, then you can modify it.

2).

```
 char *p_NUM="ABC";

 p_NUM[0]='D';

 puts(p_NUM);

 return 0;
```

A variable that points to a string literal can’t be used to change the contents of the string. So this one will return an error.

3).

```
 int NUM[] = {1, 2, 3};
 int *p_NUM = NUM;

 p_NUM[0]=4;

 puts(p_NUM);
 printf("%i\n",p_NUM);

 int i;
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)printf("%i",p_NUM[i]);


 return 0;
```

the result of `puts(p_NUM);` and `printf("%i\n",p_NUM);` is quite funny. I don't know why.

4).

```
int *p_NUM = { 1, 2, 3 };

p_NUM[0] = 4;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%i", p_NUM[i]);

return 0;
```

This one compiler return a error,that means point to a integer array can not be used to modify the array, correct?

5).

```
int NUM[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; int * p_NUM = NULL; // integer pointer

p_NUM = NUM; // integer pointer pointing to integer array
```

If I write like this, is it the same?

```
int NUM[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int * p_NUM = NUM; // integer pointer pointing to integer array
```

Comment: what do you think `int *p_NUM = { 1, 2, 3 };` is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `char NUM[] = "ABC";`

`NUM` is an array of `char`s, initialized with the value of `"ABC"`. It is in read-write memory. It has a size of `4`, including the null terminator.

---

2. `char *p_NUM="ABC";`

`p` is the pointer to the string literal `"ABC"`. `"ABC"`  is placed in read-only memory and hence cannot be modified.

---

3. `int NUM[] = {1, 2, 3};`

same as point 1. integer array. However, by saying `for(i=0;i<4;i++)`, you're runnning past the allocated memory, creating `off-by-one` error which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to change your loop condition to `for(i=0;i<3;i++)` as array indexing in `C` starts from `0`.

---

4. `int *p_NUM = { 1, 2, 3 };`

Invaild. Error case. `p_NUM` is ***not*** a **pointer to an integer array**. Your compiler should have produced warnings sifficiently. In this case, first, the brace enclosed list will be treated as initializer to `p`. It will produce twofold warnings

4.1. `warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`
   4.2. `excess elements in scalar initializer`

What you wanted instead is

```
int NUM[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int * p_NUM = NULL;              // integer pointer

p_NUM = NUM;                     // integer pointer pointing to integer array

p_NUM[0] = 4;                    //access array element thr' pointer and index

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)          //notice the change here
    printf("%i", p_NUM[i]);

return 0;
```

Comment: It's the same to my point 3. but you initialize p_NUM to NULL first then to NUM, is there a difference?

Comment: @LeeWilliam what is same to point 3? Did you read my complete answer?

Comment: "what you want instead is...", that is the same code as in my point 3. but you initialize p_NUM to NULL first then to NUM, is there a difference?

Comment: "p_NUM is not a pointer to an integer array." So what should I call it?

Comment: @LeeWilliam It _may_ look same, but it's way different than your previous point 4. i make `p_NUM` pointer to hold the address of `NUM` array.

Comment: Yes, check my point 3 code please. I think it's the same as yours.

Comment: @LeeWilliam In ___your___ point 4, `p_NUM` is a pointer but  _not a pointer to an integer array_. There is no array in your point 4, actually. Read about [initalizer list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)#Initializer).

Comment: I thought { 1, 2, 3 } is called integer array. If not what should I call it?

Comment: `{ 1, 2, 3 }` , in that particular form, is not integer array. As it is written now, it's an initializer list.